# mapping missing values in one column of pandas dataframe using dictionary with reference to another column values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe as

```
> print(df)
[Out:]
activity-code    activity
-------------------------
0                unknown
99               NaN
84               sports
72;99            NaN
57               recreational
57;99;11         NaN
11               NaN
```

and a dictionary with activity-codes as keys,

```
> print(act_dict)
[Out:]
{10: 'unknown',
11: 'cultural',
57: 'recreational',
72: 'social service',
84: 'sports',
99: 'education'}
```

**All the values inside the dataframe are stored as strings even the activity-code has values as string. Whereas the dictionary keys are of integer type**
I want to somehow map and replace with missing values in activity using the dictionary with reference to the values stored in activity-code column.
So the desired output dataframe should be something like this,

```
> print(df)
[Out:]
activity-code    activity
-------------------------
0                unknown
99               education
84               sports
72;99            social service;education
57               recreational
57;99;11         recreational;education;cultural
11               cultural
```

This is what I've tried so far,

```
df['new-activity'] = df['activity-code'].str.split(';').apply(lambda x: ';'.join([act_dict[int(i)] for i in x]))
```

but I'm getting KeyError for single values where the activity-codes aren't single code values. The error says `KeyError: 0`

How do i map the dictionary values to the missing values in activity column of dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `apply` and `str.split`, than in `apply`, use a list comprehension and join it by `';'`:

```
df['activity'] = df['activity-code'].str.split(';').apply(lambda x: ';'.join([act_dict[int(i)] for i in x]))
```

And now:

```
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  activity-code                         activity
0             0                          unknown
1            99                        education
2            84                           sports
3         72;99         social service;education
4            57                     recreational
5      57;99;11  recreational;education;cultural
6            11                         cultural
```

Comment: Hi @U9-Forward Please see the description in question, I already tried this approach.....I'm getting KeyError for records where there's a single activity-code.....this line of code works for records where there are multiple activity-codes in the same record but not at places where there's only single activity-code

Comment: I just rechecked it was probabaly because the dictionary had no key value pair for '0'. I'm sorry it was a mistake on my end, I never validated the keys in dictionary. But thanks....the moment you said it worked for you, i just cross checked and found out I didn't had any key as zero. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Well in case there is no values against 0 in your dictionary you can use filter():

```
df['activity']= df['activity-code'].apply(lambda x:'; '.join(list(filter(None,map(act_dict.get,list(map(int,x.split(';'))))))))
```